# show single row through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a named array in php

```
$notes=[
      ['Fname','John'],['lname:','smith'], 
      ['Fname','david'],['lname:','rock']
];
```

I retreive the array via ajax and in my ajax success function,
I know this gets each first name, but, I only want to retrieve one row .

```
 $.each(result.data.notes, function (index, data) {
      console.log(data['fname'];)
 });
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is your expected result?

Comment: use index and no need to loop if you need one row only. but be sure you know which index the data is in

Comment: at the moment the out put comming is  John  david   , I only want to output John.

Comment: what row do you need?

Comment: try following result.data.notes[0].Fname

Comment: `['Fname','John']` is an array, so it has no property called Fname

Comment: Your data would be better off as `{"Fname": "John", "lname": "smith" }` - are you able to change what the server sends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax success function, you don't have to loop through the returned ajax data if you only want to get the first property of the first row, as according to your question ajax is returning the whole array. Just get the first Fname property from the first row if that is what you want.

```
if(result.data.notes[0] && result.data.notes[0].Fname){
    result.data.notes[0].Fname
}
```